# How do I install Datastax-PHP driver for Cassandra on Windows?

Tags: php, cassandra, installation, driver, datastax

I am trying to install Datastax PHP driver for Cassandra from [here](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver) and according to [these](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/README.md#installing-with-pecl) instructions.
So far I have installed these dependencies: Bison, CMake, Git, ActiveState Perl, and Python. However, when I run the batch file mentioned in the instructions (`vc_build.bat`) it reports the next error:

```
Update cpp-driver submodule ... FAILED

See D:\php-driver-master\php-driver-master\ext\\build\log\cpp-driver.log for more details

Bison Not Found in PATH: Bison is required to complete build

Ensure Bison is installed in C:\GnuWin32
```

Also, the content of the `cpp-driver.log` file is:

```
Update cpp-driver submodule 
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

The problem is I already added the `C:\GnuWin32` in the *Path* system variable by appending the `;C:\GnuWin32` to the string associated in the *Path* variable.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with the checking function in vc_build.bat. Just comment out the BISON checking in that file as below and you can make it work.

```
REM Ensure additional build dependencies are installed
REM SET "PATH=!PATH!;!SYSTEMDRIVE!\GnuWin32\bin"
REM CALL :GETFULLPATH "!BISON!" BISON_FOUND
REM IF NOT DEFINED BISON_FOUND (
REM   ECHO Bison Not Found in PATH: Bison is required to complete build
REM   ECHO Ensure Bison is installed in !SYSTEMDRIVE!\GnuWin32
REM   ECHO.
REM   ECHO  !DOWNLOAD_URL_BISON!
REM   CHOICE /N /T 15 /D N /M "Would you like to download Bison now?"
REM   IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU !YES! START !DOWNLOAD_URL_BISON!
REM   EXIT /B !EXIT_CODE_MISSING_BUILD_DEPENDENCY!
REM )
```